# Memory consumption for sockets in linux & compaction behavior

Tags: linux, sockets, memory, linux-kernel, centos

Our system had a memory footprint growing gradually.
After doing too many debugging with the profilers, didnt reach the exact point of issue.
Now after verifying random things on the system, it got cornered to the websockets we used.

Those sockets had a lot of unread messages in its queue. Memory usage was directly proportional to the number of messages. By clearing up the messages in queue, there was a huge memory reclaimed.

Problem:

Tested OS version: CentOS 7.5

- I tried checking the memory occupied by the sockets using **'/proc/net/sockstat'**
  the mem column showed the memory was ~300mb
- Total memory for the recv-Q ~6mb measured using **netstat -tunp** (treated the numbers in recv-Q as bytes)

But when i cleaned up the unread messages, I got ~1.5gb of memory reclaimed. (using **free** command)

Anything else to be checked to get the right memory usage for sockets?

Is that an unwanted memory usage done by linux? How to debug the memory used by sockets further?

Why linux tools like **top** isnt listing the memory usage for sockets? It shows us the memory for processes, cache and buffers, but why not sockets.

Additional details:
Changing the memory allocator to jemalloc didnt stop this memory growth. So it is not an issue associated with glibc.

=================================================================

**Edited Info: After doing some work with the test application**

Converted our problem into a simple test program and ran it in servers with different kernel versions.

The test program: 5000 sockets and 4 incoming messages(3 bytes per message) to that socket every minute. Also did some work on using the ss -tm to clearly understand the buffer memory behavior.

Machine 1: Kernel: 2.6.32
/proc/sys/net/core/rmem_max=124928

At start: Free mem: 2.5gb
For every incoming message, mem in ss -tm grew by 512 bytes per socket.
At some point, there was a sudden drop in memory usage by sockets.

Before memory drop:

> free -m : free memory: 1.1G
>
> sockstat: TCP: inuse 6 orphan 1 tw 161 alloc 5265 **mem 114138**
>
> ss -tm : mem:(**r112784**,w0,f1904,t0)

After memory drop:

> free -m free memory: 2.3G
>
> sockstat TCP: inuse 6 orphan 1 tw 157 alloc 5266 **mem 8042**
>
> ss -tm mem:(**r9528**,w0,f952,t0)

Values in recv-Q was constantly increasing with the expected values.

It was the point where "r" value reached approx equal to core/rmem_max
Seemed like a compaction process happened there.

Machine 2: Kernel: 3.10.0
/proc/sys/net/core/rmem_max=212992

Here I expected that memory will get dropped at ~212992. But this machine had the upgraded version ss which showed the rb=367360 size itself. So waited for the exact compaction process to happen.

At start:

> ss -tm : skmem:(r0,rb367360,t0,tb87040,f53248,w0,o0,bl0)
>
> sockstat: TCP: inuse 4 orphan 0 tw 97 alloc 5042 mem 4992

Here also the memory kept on increasing in the expected rate. There was memory drop at a particular point of time.

**At memory drop point 1:**
Before memory drop:

> free : free memory: 2.1gb
>
> sockstat : TCP: inuse 4 orphan 0 tw 89 alloc 5097 mem 354398
>
> ss -tm : skmem:(r290560,rb367360,t0,tb87040,f256,w0,o0,bl0)

After memory drop:

> free : free memory: 3.1gb
>
> sockstat : TCP: inuse 4 orphan 0 tw 93 alloc 5099 mem 187542
>
> coming to ss -tm, saw a different behavior this time:
>
> 50% of the sockets had compacted values,
>
> skmem:(r4352,rb367360,t0,tb87040,f3840,w0,o0,bl0)
>
> and the remaining had actual values (not compacted)
>
> skmem:(r291072,rb367360,t0,tb87040,f3840,w0,o0,bl0)

So compaction happened soon before "r" value reached "rb"

Next, waited till the "r" value reaches "rb"

**Memory drop point 2**
There the next point of memory drop happened. All the socket buffers were compacted.(except 100 sockets) and huge memory was reclaimed.

=================================================================

**Now my understanding:**

The actual problem we faced in our servers: The memory footprint was growing continuously and machine started using swap space and got slowed down. Now after running the test programs, I understood that the free space available in our servers were not enough to hold till the point of compaction.

**My Questions:**

1. Is this compaction a inbuilt behavior of socket buffers?
2. If yes, when will that happen, in Machine 2, i had different experience than the one in machine 1? Which value should be tuned to bring the compaction early?
3. "mem" value in sockstat and sum of "r" value in ss add up to give the total memory occupied by the socket? Or they are same values listed by different tools.

(As per my tests, I see (mem value sockstat + skmem buffer value) equals the memory getting freed up.)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42992661/1216776

Comment: @stark I think, I've posted both the categories discussed there. mem from sockstat and queue related memory. Please point out if anything is missed out. Thanks.

Comment: As it says in the linked post, that memory is kernel memory, not process memory. So it won't be shown in top and has nothing to do with glibc or its allocator.

Comment: Ok got it. "ss -m are maximum values (constrained with tcp_rmem and `tcp_wmem), not the currently allocated values". I got some output contradictory to this information. skmem:(r64768,rb367360,t0,tb87040,f768,w0,o0,bl0) this is my socket mem. r64768 is in bytes right. With increase in this r value, the free memory is getting decreased. Is this related to /proc/sys/net/core/rmem_max. value: 212992 Also got to know that kernel will allocate more space than rmem_max to accommodate additional kernel data structures.

Comment: In another machine with /proc/sys/net/core/rmem_max. value: 124928, memory grow till mem:(r111888,w0,f2800,t0) r ~= rmem_max, then it suddenly gets dropped to mem:(r9432,w0,f2856,t0) . Is this a compaction process to release up the free memory in buffers? Recv-Q just had 7473 bytes when this happened.

Comment: How did you finally measure tcp memory usage from `ss`??? I am trying to figure out a similar problem, but unfortuantely I seem to be missing something. `mem` in **sockstat** * 4k is not equal to the `skmem` columns of `ss`. You can see the more detailed question here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/623775/calculate-tcp-memory-usage-does-not-add-up

Answer (score 0):

> Is this compaction a inbuilt behavior of socket buffers?

Yes.. tcp_collapse method takes care of that. To accomodate more space, it compacts them. This collapsing process comes with a CPU overhead and tcp parameters should be tuned to avoid this process in normal situations.

Netstat -sn | grep 'prune|collapse' gives us the no. of packets collapsed/pruned

> If yes, when will that happen, in Machine 2, i had different experience than the one in machine 1? Which value should be tuned to bring the compaction early?

Generally this collapsing is a CPU intensive process and linux experts didnt want that to happen early. There were few checkins to tcp module to delay the collapse event. If pruned or collapsed packets are there, you are missing something with your configurations or your app logic.

Controlling behavior explained in man page:
            /proc/sys/net/core/rmem_max - setting this for all kind of sockets (in pages)
            /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_rmem - helps overriding the limits for tcp sockets (in pages)

Comment: did you actually find an answer to your question no3: _"mem" value in sockstat and sum of "r" value in ss add up to give the total memory occupied by the socket? Or they are same values listed by different tools._  ??? I am having a similar problem and want to better understand socket memory usage